# How would I correctly .catch this?

Tags: javascript, try-catch, discord, eris

I'm trying to catch `// this line`, but I can't seem to find where to put the catch to correctly catch it.

````
      mutedList.forEach((i) => {
      if (i.mutedEnd*1000 < new Date()){
        console.log(i)
        db.collection('muted').doc(i.userID).get().then((q) => {
        db.collection('muted').doc(i.userID).update({
          stillMuted: false
        }).then(
          bot.guilds.get(i.guildID).members.get(i.userID).removeRole(i.mutedRole) // this line | here
        ).catch((err) => {
          bot.createMessage('717822384198910042',{ embed: {
            title: 'ERROR',
            description: '```js\n'+err.stack+'\n```',
            color: hex
          }});
      })}
    )}
  })
````

I've tried where it is currently, and where I put a `HERE`

Comment: You need to pass a callback function to `then`, not a promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't `.catch();` that line as it is not a promise.

Try this code, you may be getting errors because you are trying to use methods on something that may be returning `undefined` so this checks that the guild and member exist before performing any methods on it.

```
then(() => {
    const guild = bot.guilds.get(i.guildID);
    if (guild) const member = guild.members.get(i.userID);
    if (member) member.removeRole(i.mutedRole);
})
```

The `.catch();` you currently have is only for handling rejections on the original promise `db.collection('muted').doc(i.userID).update`

I also noticed you're using Discord.js v11, I recommend updating to v12 as v11 will be scrapped by the end of October.